# Unity Vector2.Lerp "t" doesn't work as expected, it's to quickly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can not get the position of the object takes 20 seconds to change from point A to B, because it moves faster than it should, but the message "Ready" does take 20 seconds to appear as it should.

What am I overlooking?

```
private bool canMove = true;

...

private IEnumerator SmoothMove() {
    canMove = false;
    Vector2 target = new Vector2(transform.position.x + 1.5f, transform.position.y);

    float moveDurationTimer = 0.0f;
    float moveDuration = 20f;

    while (moveDurationTimer < moveDuration) {
        moveDurationTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, target, moveDurationTimer / moveDuration);
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("Ready");
    canMove = true;
}
```

<s>I'm using a coroutine that I call from Update().</s>

**Edit:**

When I said "I'm using a coroutine that I call from Update()", I had to have been more specific, sorry:

```
void Update() {

    if (canMove && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            StartCoroutine(SmoothMove());
        }
}
```

Comment: If you start it in `Update` **every frame** you get multiple concurrent Coroutines and each of them moves your object a little bit so with each frame more your object is moved further within one frame ....

Comment: I had to have been more specific. I updated the problem, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that `Lerp` interpolates between the two input values!

You always pass in the new current position so it now interpolates starting from a new start

```
transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, target, moveDurationTimer / moveDuration);
```

---

What you rather want to do is store the initial position and use that one instead

```
private IEnumerator SmoothMove() 
{
    canMove = false;
    // Store initial value
    var startPos = transform.position;

    Vector2 target = new Vector2(transform.position.x + 1.5f, transform.position.y);

    float moveDurationTimer = 0.0f;
    float moveDuration = 20f;

    while (moveDurationTimer < moveDuration) {
        moveDurationTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        // Lerp using initial value!
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, target, moveDurationTimer / moveDuration);
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("Ready");
    canMove = true;
}
```

Comment: You solved my problem, thanks you very much. I appreciate your time and your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than starting your coroutine from Update, kick it off from Start.

[image: Example]

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Traveler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _movementDuration = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _wayPointOne = null;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _wayPointTwo = null;
    [SerializeField] private float _percentComplete = 0.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move());
    }

    private IEnumerator Move()
    {
        var startMoveTime = Time.time;
        while (Time.time - startMoveTime < _movementDuration)
        {
            _percentComplete = (Time.time - startMoveTime) / _movementDuration;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_wayPointOne.position, _wayPointTwo.position, _percentComplete);
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.position = _wayPointTwo.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Since you have a specific **duration** for the movement, you can use a while loop in the IEnumerator to lerp your transform.position in a predicatable way.

Comment: Great explanation, but I had to have been more specific, sorry. I updated the problem, thanks for your answer.

Comment: The problem isn't caused by starting it in `Update`, so why recommend not doing that? There are perfectly valid reasons for starting a coroutine in `Update`. You do make the necessary change in having a constant value for the first argument of `Lerp` but you don't actually mention doing that or explain why.